# Yii error when i try remove www prefix

Tags: .htaccess, yii, seo

With .htaccess i successfully remove index.php from url. 
For good SEO practice I need to remove WWW prefix. Combination two Apache rules gives an error.

I type www.site.com, i got site.ru  - ok!

I type www.site.com/catalog, i got site.ru - error! its main page.

I type www.site.com/page/some_page, i got site/index.php/some_page - error!

(note: **rules** 'page/' => 'site/page', 'catalog/' => 'site/catalog/',)

---

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks


#redirect from WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://%1/$1 [L,R=permanent]


#remove index.php from url
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: I'm also having this problem...Anybody know how to fix this???

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

In place of

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://%1/$1 [L,R=permanent]
```

Hope it would help.

Comment: trouble in other part. when i leave in.htaccess only:
   #redirect from WWW
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
   RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://%1/$1 [L,R=permanent]

its work, but with index.php in URL :(

Comment: I hope you did this in config `'urlFormat'=>'path',
'showScriptName'=>false,`